# Adding icon to dojo data grid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'd like to set a icon in a column in a dojox data grid. Can I set the class icon like in the dojo tree: `dijit/Tree` `getIconClass`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should try formatter

```
<script>
    function imgFormatter(s) {
        return '<img src="' + s + '"/>';
    }
</script>
 <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid">
     <thead>
         <tr>
              <th field="col" formatter="imgFormatter"></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
 </table>
```